# Finding the Closest/Nearest value in relation to X and Y Coordinates Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have been struggling with an issue for days now. I have an excel sheet with a lot of data about Airports in Europe. For simplicity sake, i will narrow it down to few columns which are all in the same table.

Column D = **IATA CODES** ("The Name code" for each airport, for example Name: Eindhoven airport -> IATA: EIN

Column J = Airport (D) **Y Coordinates**

Column K = Airport (D) **X Coordinates**

Now my goal is that blank column (N) provides my with the IATA CODES (D) of each airport which is the closest/nearest.

For example:

VALUE (D2) = **TIA**

VALUE (J2) = **41.4146995544**

VALUE (K2) = **19.7206001282**

VALUE (N2) = Here I want to find the closest airport, in relation to the coordinates

I have already tried to:
1. Convert the coordinates Y [J] and X [K] Into a single value and then use the function

*<=INDEX([IATA],MATCH(MIN(ABS(M3:M1045-M2)),ABS(M3:M1045-M2),0))>.*

In this formula Column [M] is the single value of the coordinates. The problems I faced where that

1.1 The single value of Y [J] and X [K] was inaccurate

1.2 The Formula did not display accurate results

1.3 I still do not know how to apply the formule while Ignoring the values within the same row. For example, obviously, Excel would say the closest airport to 'EIN' = 'EIN' as it is an exact match!

2. I have also seen many people use the LARGE and SMALL function, but I want to find the airport that is the closest whether the value is Higher or Lower.

Can someone plesae help me solve this puzzle :)

Comment: "Convert the coordinates Y [J] and X [K] Into a single value" How??? By doing so you just lose the opportunity to calculate distance

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to generate a table with all the distances between airports based on the formula for distance on a plane (`SQRT((X - X')^2 + (Y - Y')^2)`) then use `Index/Match` with that table.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Yes I have figured out that formula for flights themselves as I then Know the Source and destination. The only problem with applying that formula now is that I have 1044 airports in my sheet. If I'd apply the formula to every combo possibility, it would cost me a lifetime :/

Comment: @MátéJuhász yes, I figured. So I am trying to find another way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to generate a table of all distances fairly quickly:

1. generate a table of all X-Y  coordinates (I assume you already have this)

[image]

2. Create a table with all the airports listed in the header and in the first column

[image]

3. In `B2`, insert the following formula:

   ```
   =SQRT((VLOOKUP($A2,$I$1:$K$4,2)-VLOOKUP(B$1,$I$1:$K$4,2))^2+(VLOOKUP($A2,$I$1:$K$4,3)-VLOOKUP(B$1,$I$1:$K$4,3))^2)
   ```
4. Copy and paste the formula to fill the entire table

[image]

Once you have the table you can use the following formula to find the nearest airport:

```
=INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(SMALL(OFFSET(A2:A4,0,MATCH(O2,B1:D1)),2),OFFSET(A2:A4,0,MATCH(O2,B1:D1)),0))
```

[image]

To get the second closest, third closest and so on, change the `2` parameter in the `SMALL` part of the formula to `3`, `4` and so on.
(note: I put all this one one sheet, but you probably won't want to, adjust ranges as required)

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much for the reply! So I came untill step 4 where some weird things happened :/. I filled every cell and it worked for about 60% of the cells. but I got a lot of N/A errors in others. After checking each cell, I couldn't find any mistake that I could have made. However I did find a pattern that every N/A error was in a cell where the IATA value ('ABC' 'DEF'), started with the letter 'A' or 'B'. Very weird.. Furthermore I have got some blank cells (outside from the cells that match (ABC:ABC->0)). Do you know what it the error here? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The codes in the reference table (the one with the X-Y coordinates) will need to be sorted alphabetically

Comment: Alright thanks!!, now I entered the step: my formula I used regarding your step was (BEGIN)=INDEX(Blad3!A3:A1046,MATCH(MINIFS(OFFSET(Blad3!A3:A1046,0,MATCH(M3,Blad3!B2:ANE2)),OFFSET(Blad3!A3:A1046,0,MATCH(M3,Blad3!B2:ANE2)),"<>0"),OFFSET(Blad3!A3:A1046,0,MATCH(M3,Blad3!B2:ANE2)),0))(END) In this Formula Blad3 is the New 'Distance' sheet, in which A1:A1045 is the vertical range and B1:ANE1 is the horizantal range. Furthermore, M2 (on the Main Sheet) is where I want the closest airport to show [ABC]. However now the value returns '0' in every cell. We're so close :0.

Comment: But am I that stupid or is this exactly to same formula?

Comment: No, I am and copied the wrong one <facepalm>

Comment: Try `=INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(SMALL(OFFSET(A2:A4,0,MATCH(O2,B1:D1)),2),OFFSET(A2:A4,0,MATCH(O2,B1:D1)),0))`

Comment: Omg it works thank you so much!!! Just to be sure, it calculates the nearest now right? (It does not matter whether the value is higher or lower in the calculation, right?). Furthermore to be the complete savior of the day. How can I now find the second closest, third closest etc.?

Comment: Change the `2` parameter in the `SMALL` part of the formula `to `3`, `4` and so on (and feel free to mark the answer as correct so people know this question is answered)

Comment: Will do so, thank you so much!!